# finding percentage of total np.Nan values in the data frame using numpy or pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to find the percentage of missing values (`np.nan`) in python using NumPy and Pandas.
I am using this code line:

```
print(df.isnull().sum().sum())
```

but it shows 0 as the result.

Comment: The code should work, have you checked if you actually have null values in your dataframe?

Comment: yes, I recently replaced all the missing values with np.Nan, previously it was denoted by '?'

Comment: shoudn't be `df.isnull.sum().sum() / df.size` ?

Comment: if you get `0` for `df.isnull.sum().sum()` then it can't find `np.nan`. Maybe you have strings `"np.nan"` - you could get some `np.nan` from `df` and check `type()`

Comment: upload/embed sample datasets and expected output. then we can suggest the code